# Create instance of ES6 class from JSON result

Tags: javascript, es6-class, monkeypatching, prototypal-inheritance

What's the easiest way to create an instance of an ES6 class from a JSON object? E.g., given something like:

```js
class Foo
  constructor(bar) {
    this.bar = bar
  }
  frob() {
    console.log(`frobbed ${this.bar}`)
  }
}
```

and an API call returning:

```json
{ "bar": "baz" }
```

how can I get the equivalent of something like this?

```js
let foo = new Foo("baz")
```

I.e., something like:

```js
async function frobResult() {
  let result = await fetch('/foo') // returns { "bar": "baz" }
  
  // ...magic happens here?

  result.frob()                    // logs "frobbed baz" to console
}
```

Obviously I could make the constructor take the JSON object and pull `bar` out of it, or write a factory function that does something similar, but I'd rather not have to either call each property out by name, and ideally I'd rather not have to loop over `getOwnPropertyNames()` or similar either. Is there any way, for instance, that I can just monkey-patch the JSON object to extend `Foo`?

---

**ETA:** Of the answers, [Rahul Kumar's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68480339/27358) `Object.setPrototypeOf()` is the exact monkey-patch solution I was asking for, but [CertainPerformance's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68479598/27358) `Object.assign()` is especially useful when you have not just a class, but a complex object with its own state that you don’t want to lose, such as a Vue component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Object.setPrototypeOf()` method to set the prototype of `result` object to the prototype of `Foo`.

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(bar) {
    this.bar = bar
  }
  frob() {
    console.log(`frobbed ${this.bar}`);
  }
}

function frobResult() {
  let result = { bar: "baz" }; // Mock fetch api result
  Object.setPrototypeOf(result, Foo.prototype);
  console.log(result);
  result.frob();
}

frobResult();
```

Comment: Exactly the monkey-patch solution I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.create` to create an object whose internal prototype is `Foo.prototype`, and whose own properties are the API object's:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(bar) {
    this.bar = bar
  }
  frob() {
    console.log(`frobbed ${this.bar}`)
  }
}
const apiObj = { "bar": "baz" };

const instance = Object.assign(Object.create(Foo.prototype), apiObj);
console.log(instance);
instance.frob();
```

Comment: [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) is the trick — thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the object, or its properties, into the constructor.

```js
async function frobResult() {
  const result = await fetch('/foo') // returns { "bar": "baz" }
  // ...magic happens here?
  const foo = new Foo(result.bar);
  foo.frob()                    // logs "frobbed baz" to console
}
```

Comment: That works OK for this toy example, but it gets ugly if there are a lot of properties.